# How to truncate each directory to n chars in a path using sed/awk?

Tags: regex, awk, sed

For example with n being 3, `p1ath/p2ath/p3ath` would become `p1a/p2a/p3`?

I don't understand how to:

1. Truncate a capture group (`\1`, `\2`, etc..)   using sed.
2. How to make the capture groups 'dynamic' rather being a set static number of capture groups?

So far I have `'s/\(.*\)\//\1\//g'`

Comment: Do you want only to truncate strings or rename directories, too?

Comment: Just truncate the string. So for example using the command `echo "path1/path2/path3" | sed -e 's/\(.*\)\//\1\//g'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With GNU sed:

```
echo "p1ath/p2ath/p3ath" | sed -r 's|([^/]{3})[^/]*|\1|g'
```

Output:

```
p1a/p2a/p3a
```

---

See: [The Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/3776858)